# TFS: How to convert a pending delete + add to edit?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, ide

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the Team Foundation Server 2017.

The case is:

1. I deleted all files from a directory under source control. (using the solution explorer)
2. with a external tool created a new ones:

   2.a) some files has the same name as the deleted ones.

   2.b) some files are new.

   2.c) some files does not exists anymore.

In the Pending Changes I see the (2.b) and (2.c) correctly, but not the (2.a).

There is a "detected adds". When I try to promote these adds, it throws an error "The item XX already has pending changes.".

[detected adds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcIFv.png)

So, the question is: how can I merge these changes? (the deletes with the detected adds to become edits)
The expected behavior is a single check-in with all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you want to delete files + add  new files with the same name in one go pending change(a single changeset).

It's impossible, cause the file is **with pending delete status**. Since you haven't checked in the pending changes, the file is still exist in server path.  You need to do this separately, otherwise you will get a warning prompt up as below:

[image]

So you have to do this in two steps:

- First check in the pending deletes for the old changes
- Then promote the new adds from detected list and check in the new adds which have the "same name"

Everything should work properly, just have two changesets in history.

Comment: Just for note, I just did it in one changeset. First I do a "checkout for edit" to the entire folder, then "exclude from the project" that folder. Then I delete all the files from that folder (using windows explorer) and recreate the new ones with the tool. Then in the Team explorer I "promote" the detected adds and deletes. And now the changeset contains Adds, Deletes and Edits. So, an edit + delete can be merged, but not the delete + add.